# Improper Integral $\int_0^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ \text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have to find the value of:
$$\int_0^2 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ \text{d}x$$
Here is my work so far:
$$\int_0^2 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ \text{d}x$$
$$=\int_0^2 x^{-1/2} \ \text{d}x$$
$$=\left.2x^{1/2}\right|_0^2$$
At this point I was about to apply the Fundamental Theorem, then I realized that the function is discontinuous at $x=0$, so the integral does not exist. However, the answer is $2\sqrt{2}$, which is what I would have gotten *if* the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus *could* have been applied. First, how would I get $2\sqrt{2}$, and second, is it simply a coincidence that the answer is $2\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: This is an indefinite integral. What's meant is the limit of $\int_\varepsilon^2$ as $\varepsilon$ goes to zero.

Comment: Your integral is called *indefinite* or *improper* integral and it's convergent integral.

Comment: This is an *improper* integral.  It is evaluated as @Mike describes.  (It's very much a definite integral.)

Comment: @Mike Please explain the difference between a definite integral and an indefinite integral thank you very much

Comment: The integrand is not defined at $x=0$, you have to replace it by $0+\delta$ and take limit as $\delta \to 0$

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks, I always mess that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $1/\sqrt{x}$ is not defined at $0$, so it's an abuse of notation to write $$\int_0^2 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx$$

You're really being asked to compute the improper integral $$ \lim_{t \to 0^+} \int_t^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$

Comment: So all I have to do is replace $0$ with $t$ (provided that $t > 0$), apply the Fundamental Theorem, and let $t$ approach $0$. Thanks!